# HTTPS request on iphone not sent to server

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am developing an application for iphone using phonegap.
When submitting ajax requests using HTTP everything works fine. But when i switch to HTTPS, the requests aren't sent to the server. The same code works for HTTP and HTTPS on android.

Below is the code i am using, thank you for your help in advance

```
var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
    url : "https://test.com",
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : "text; charset=utf-8",
    data : sr,
    dataType : "text",
    headers : { SOAPAction : '"'+soapaction+ '"' },
    success : function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log("----- xmlRequest.responseText: " + xmlRequest.responseText);
        SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, sch, data);
    },
    error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log("----- xmlRequest.responseText: " + xmlRequest.responseText);
        console.log("----- errorThrown = " + errorThrown + " textStatus = "+ textStatus );
        ServiceErrorMessage(method, jqXHR.status, errorThrown, xmlRequest.responseText);
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end of your AppDelegate.m file

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; 
}
@end
```

Comment: Does this breach the iOS guidelines? Is this a private API?